# Hide a MapBox Marker on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, mapbox

I want to hide a MapBox Marker on Android, and when I do a zoom I want to show it.
Is there a function on MapBox like "setVisible(true or false)" of GoogleMaps Marker ? 
In GoogleMap you can hide a marker like that :

```
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(49.685, 50.658))  
                .title("Paris"));
    marker.setVisible(false); // hide the marker
```

Is there any function on MapBox which do the same ? Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I edit my post whith some code, I hope that it's more easy to understand now.

Answer (score 2):

There currently isn't a `.setVisible` method exposed for use in the Mapbox Android SDK. My suggestion would be to just remove the marker and re-add it when you need to.